# Package/directory conventions in Java

Tags: java, directory, project, package, conventions

I want to use `christophel.joel` as my root package until I get a domain name. Which of the following is a better practice?

- Different set of `christophel` and `joel` folders for each project

  Example:
  \Project Name\christophel\joel\subdirectory\ClassName.java

**-OR-**

- Only one set of `christophel` and `joel` folders

  Example:
  \christophel\joel\projectname\subdirectory\ClassName.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use package structure like one you specified then first option will be the preferred.
But as per Java coding convention you should use reverse structure of your domain (if any) name for example:

```
com.example.functionalityCategory
```